# "How are we?" vs. "How are you?"

Tags: meaning, differences

What's the appropriate response to "How are we?" and what is it actually referring to?

Comment: "We", in this sense, is kind of like the "royal we", only in reverse.  Often used when "talking down" to a child, or simply when "being familiar" with the individual.  "How are we?" basically means "How are you?", but leaves things open to mention family and friends in response to the query.

Comment: Television cooks do it, too: "We" cut up the onion and saute it in vegetable oil.

Comment: It's impossible for people of a certain age to hear that question and not feel the infantilizing echoes of A.A. Milne's titles—"When We Were Very Young" and "Now We Are Six"—rustling ghostlike across the years. So the next time someone asks you, "How are we today?" you might consider answering, simply, "Now we are six!"

Answer (score 5):

The 'we' in "how are we" is the same 'we' used when a teacher asks a child "Why don't we put down the toy and wash up for lunch?"  Dictionary.com:

> 7. you (used familiarly, often with mild condescension or sarcasm, as in addressing a child, a patient, etc.):
>      *We know that's naughty, don't we? It's time we took our medicine.*

"How are we?" Is the question a nurse might ask you when entering the room: "Oh, and how are we doing today?"  The proper response is the same response given to "How are you," however truthful or terse you wish to keep said response.

Answer (score 1):

"How are we doing" is a patronizing way of asking, "How are you doing?"

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Please note that we follow a strict question-and-answer format here and your answer does not seem to address the question. If you can, please [edit] it to elaborate.